# MYSQL-GALERA Cluster

Tags: mysql

While connecting my galera node which is in aws ec2 instances to my mysql-galera cluster which are in not in aws but are dedicated servers the connection is aborting after several minutes after executing wsrep command to join cluster.
Can anyone provide the solution?

Comment: You're probably going to have to debug this yourself to work out which end is dropping the connection and why. If you don't have any better ideas then you could run tcpdump at each end, filtered only for packets between the two hosts, and capture the connection drop then analyse this in wireshark to see which end dropped the connection as a first step, and maybe see which layer of protocol the connection drop happened at, but unless someone has seen this exact problem before I doubt anyone can just tell you what to do.

Comment: ok..
Thanks....  But I cannot run tcpdump on live server since it holds the db unless the command is completed.. it effects the cluster.